# Create a new list from value in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as

```
{'Items': [
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-22'},
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'},
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'efgh', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'}
          ]
}
```

I want to create 2 result by checking the table_name.

```
abcd_lst = [
               {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-22'},
               {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'}
           ]

efgh_lst = [
               {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'efgh', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'}
           ]
```

Comment: Hi Ariful, Is the dictionary you wish to split into lists only going to contain one entry, as in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You could have done a simple iteration to create a simple dict of lists. The same can be done by defaultdict as well.

```
items = {'Items': [
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-22'},
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'abcd', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'},
              {'stage': 'temp', 'file_status': 'NOT PROCESSED', 'table_name': 'efgh', 'filehour_key': '20200817-23'}
          ]
}


import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in items['Items']:
    d[item['table_name']].append(item)

pprint.pprint(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate over the data, storing the tables in a dictionary of lists (this would help "catch" `dicts` with equal `table_names`, ensuring they're paired/placed together.

Here's a simple code that does exactly that:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
tables = defaultdict(list) # create a dict with list as default value
# iterate over 'Items' list 
for dct in it['Items']:
    table_name = dct.get('table_name') # get the name
    tables[table_name].append(dct)  # store in dict

# you can convert `tables` to a list    
tables = list(tables.values()) # a multi-dimensional list containing the two tables

# you can unpack tables  as well
table1, table2 = tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension:

```
abcd_lst = [it for it in items['Items'] if it['table_name'] == 'abcd']
efgh_lst = [it for it in items['Items'] if it['table_name'] == 'efgh']
```

This is a nice way to do it if, as in your example, your original dictionary only contains one parent key.

List comprehension just wraps a for-loop into a single line, making it a concise way to go. Here's how it works in general:

for any original iterable such as a list:

`new_list = [<operation on element> for <element> in <original iterable>]`

You can also add an optional conditional statement, as I did above.